# Swift Regex optimization

Tags: swift, regex, string

i want to look in an array of strings to get all strings containing subbstring. This function should also work with wildcard.
I wrote this function:

```
    func wordcontains(word: String, from words: [String]) -> [String] {

    //Si il y a des jokers on utilise la methode regex
    //Sinon on utilise la methode simple car beaucoup plus rapide
        let foundWords = words.filter { otherWord in
            let wordregex = word.replacingOccurrences(of: "?", with: ".")
            if (otherWord.range(of: "[A-Z]*\(wordregex)[A-Z]*", options: .regularExpression) != nil){
                return true
            }else  {
                return false
            }

        }
        return foundWords
}
```

and it's working like that:

```
input : anagrams(word: "ARC?", from: ["BOU", "BAC", "ARCS", "ARCH", "TREE","ARCHE","PROUE"])
output : ["ARCS", "ARCH", "ARCHE"]
```

it's working well with a small array, but i need to check in an array of 300000 words and it take a while.

What is the best way to optimize the regex / function?

Perhaps there is a better approch ?

Comment: You don’t need the leading or trailing `[A-Z]*`.

Comment: But no matter what, scanning 300k strings for a substring will take time.

Comment: And create `wordregex` just once before the filter.

Comment: As far as I tested, creating an `NSRegularExpression` outside of the loop has actually some effect but only 4 times or so. (About 65s : 17s for 3000000 random words with my old MacBook.) Maybe 17s is not sufficient for your requirement. You may need other strategies than simply using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your interest, the code I used for testing.

Create a Command Line Tool project.

```
import Foundation

func wordcontains(word: String, from words: [String]) -> [String] {
    ...(exactly the same code as yours)...
}

///Creating NSRegularExpression outside of the loop
func wordcontains2(word: String, from words: [String]) -> [String] {

    let wordregex = word.replacingOccurrences(of: "?", with: ".")
    let pattern = "[A-Z]*\(wordregex)[A-Z]*"

    let regex: NSRegularExpression
    do {
        regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    } catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    let foundWords = words.filter { otherWord in
        regex.firstMatch(in: otherWord, range: NSRange(0..<otherWord.utf16.count)) != nil
    }
    return foundWords
}

/// Removing `[A-Z]*` from both ends as suggested in rmaddy's comment.
/// This assumes all words in the parameter `words` consists only capital letters.
func wordcontains3(word: String, from words: [String]) -> [String] {

    let wordregex = word.replacingOccurrences(of: "?", with: ".")

    let regex: NSRegularExpression
    do {
        regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: wordregex)
    } catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    let foundWords = words.filter { otherWord in
        regex.firstMatch(in: otherWord, range: NSRange(0..<otherWord.utf16.count)) != nil
    }
    return foundWords
}
```

Generally, creating an instance of `NSRegularExpression` is an expensive operation, so moving it outside of the loop may improve the performance (of course, in case the regex does not change), but the effect is very limited.

And I added some code for testing.

```
func makeRandomWords(_ count: Int) -> [String] {
    var words: [String] = []
    for _ in 0..<count {
        let len = Int.random(in: 3...5)
        var word = ""
        for _ in 0..<len {
            let charCode = UInt32.random(in: UInt32(UInt8(ascii: "A"))...UInt32(UInt8(ascii: "Z")))
            word.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(charCode)!))
        }
        words.append(word)
    }
    return words
}
let words = makeRandomWords(300_000) //I have found the number of words is `300000` after I wrote my comment...
do {
    let date1 = Date()
    let w1 = wordcontains(word: "ARC?", from: words)
    let date2 = Date()
    print(date2.timeIntervalSince(date1), w1)

    let date3 = Date()
    let w2 = wordcontains2(word: "ARC?", from: words)
    let date4 = Date()
    print(date4.timeIntervalSince(date3), w2)

    let date5 = Date()
    let w3 = wordcontains3(word: "ARC?", from: words)
    let date6 = Date()
    print(date6.timeIntervalSince(date5), w3)
}
```

Result:

> ```
> 6.443639039993286 ["ARCQJ", "ARCZB", "AARCI", "ARCR", "ARCR", "ARCQS", "ARCGM", "ARCKL", "UARCN", "FARCS", "ARCNA", "ARCZM", "PARCL", "ARCTA", "ARCS", "ARCE", "ARCG", "ARCE"]
> 1.7534430027008057 ["ARCQJ", "ARCZB", "AARCI", "ARCR", "ARCR", "ARCQS", "ARCGM", "ARCKL", "UARCN", "FARCS", "ARCNA", "ARCZM", "PARCL", "ARCTA", "ARCS", "ARCE", "ARCG", "ARCE"]
> 1.4359259605407715 ["ARCQJ", "ARCZB", "AARCI", "ARCR", "ARCR", "ARCQS", "ARCGM", "ARCKL", "UARCN", "FARCS", "ARCNA", "ARCZM", "PARCL", "ARCTA", "ARCS", "ARCE", "ARCG", "ARCE"]
> ```

The result may change as this code uses random words, but the consumed times may not show big difference for each run.

Comment: That's really better in term of performance that what i've done. Thanks a lot